# bindToController: Object in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Directive `bindToController` can be either boolean or object, the latter is shown [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller#example):

```
myMod.directive('myDirective', {
  controller: 'MyDirectiveController',
  bindToController: {
    name: '@'
  }
});
```

But the fact that it was not documented raises questions. Why `bindToController: { ... }` feature was made in the first place? Are there useful scenarios for it?

---

Despite bindToController [wasn't primarily intended](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/10467#issuecomment-67050879) for that, it is interesting to see how it is utilized now in `angular.component` [as `bindings` property](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0-beta.2/src/loader.js#L382) to fill the gap between 1.5 and 2.0, while `scope` bindings remain unused.

Comment: Are you asking why it can bee a boolean, or what purpose does bindToController serve?

Comment: @Brocco Neither of them, I'm asking why it can be an object. Thanks, I've refined the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stumbled across [this PR](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/10467), it is quite explanatory.

I'm not sure if there is practical benefit in having two different bindings in `scope: { ... }` and `bindToController: { ... }`. But it finally brings the bindings to prototypically inherited scope as well:

```
bindToController: {
  text: '@text',
  obj: '=obj',
  expr: '&expr'
},
scope: true
```

Answer (score 4):

`bindToController` was originally just a boolean at inception, but was migrated to allow it to be an object to be more explicit about what items/values you are binding to the controller. With it being a boolean it caused some confusion where this syntax removes that confusion about what you are adding to your controller.

The idea with why this was added was to propagate the usage of the `controllerAs` syntax to move away from `$scope` especially with the move towards angular2.

The basis for why this was added was to allow the directive injections/property bindings would now be based upon the controller instance instead of of the scope parameter.

Comment: Are there any evidences that it is an actual change towards Angular 2 that has to replace `scope: { ... }`? It occurs only in ngMock, so I had an impression that it was left for testing purposes.

Comment: There are many changes/alterations to angular 1.* that have evolved in regards to best practices ($scope going away, component's via style guides to name 2). In regards to whether this is gearing towards angular 2... controllers based upon $scope will not work in ng2, they will all be based upon instance variables attached to the controller/component.

Comment: I've checked it, and the original contributor [states](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/10467#issuecomment-67050879) that it has nothing to do with Angular 2.

Comment: The idea of `controllerAs` is about the idea of using POJOs instead of `$scope` which is a belief being carried over into ng2. That being said, the syntax of making `bindToController` as an object as well is a convenience feature to alleviate confusion, so if you want to use it, great, if you don't then don't.