# Isolated directive binding to parent function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive:

```
let directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/video-player/video-player.html',
    scope: {
        someFunction:'='
    },
    ...
}

template:
<div class="video" ng-click="vm.someFunction(vm.someId)"></div>

directive:
<video-player some-function="main.ctaClick"></video-player> //controllerAs main

export class MainController {
    ...
    someFunction(){
        // How do I get the correct this here without using $parent?
        let context = this.scope.$parent.main;
    }
}
```

Basically I am wondering if there is a way to use the context of a parent scope when two-way binding a function like this? Is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolated directive is isolated from its parent, hence the name. If there is something that should be provided to the directive by the parent, it should be passed as an attribute.

It is possible to replace isolated scope with inherited scope [and use `bindToController` binding instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31415287/3731501). However, this may indicate a design flaw.

> Is this the right way to do this?

No.